# Capture an event before Drawer opens?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to capture a Navigation Drawer event just before it opens?
I haven't seen any event for this, there is a "onDrawerOpened()" but it is when the drawer is already opened.

Comment: Couldn't you use isDrawerVisible(View drawer), isDrawerOpen(View drawer), or a DrawerListener? http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

You could Override `onDrawerSlide()` or `onDrawerStateChanged()`  in your [ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#onDrawerStateChanged%28int%29) implementation.  Or you could look into a [DrawerListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html).